# Data Annotation Index Obsoleto

Tags: base-de-datos, visual-studio, data, annotation, dataannotations

Hola como estan? estoy tratando de agregar un [Index] a un campo de una clase en net 6 MVC y me aparece un mensaje de error indicando que Index esta obsoleto y no me deja compilar, tengo instalado EF,EF para sql server, etc.
Ya hice una migración las tablas se crearon correctamente pero al tratar de agregar un indice particular a un campo, aparece ese error alguien sabe la razon?
Saludos...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El mensaje de obsolescencia es una advertencia, que no impide la compilación. El error real que te impide compilar es el que dicta que tu atributo `Index` solo es válido en declaraciones de clase. No puedes aplicarlo a una propiedad, sino a una clase como tal.

Answer (score 0):

Los mensajes de obsolescencia son advertencias (esos con el icono amarillo), no errores (esos con el ícono rojo). Las advertencias permiten la compilación, los errores no. El error real que impide compilar es el que dicta que el atributo `Index` no puede aplicarse a propiedades sino a declaraciones de clase.

En [esta entrada](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/index-attribute#:%7E:text=The%20Entity%20Framework%20Core%20IndexAttribute,to%20speed%20up%20data%20retrieval.) y [esta otra entrada](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes?tabs=data-annotations) hay información detallada sobre el uso correcto de `IndexAttribute`.

Por lo que, si quieres que tu propiedad `public int DNI { get; set; }` sea índice, la forma correcta, aplicada a tu código, es esta:

```
[Index(nameof(DNI))]
public class Contacto
{
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    public int DNI { get; set; }
}
```